# Laravel newQuery()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've been looking at the newQuery eloquent model and best case uses and I can see the benefit in searching / filtering products based on a search page however is it possible to call the newQuery on only the Users related products?

For example, I have 2 models.

- User
- Product

User has many products and I have the relationship defined on the user model.

```
public function products() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
};
```

Now, previously if I wanted to filter all the products and take user out of the scenario I could use:

```
$query = (new \App\Product)->newQuery();

if($request->get('category')){
  $query->whereHas('category',function($q) use($request){
     $q->where('category_id',$request->get('category'));
  });
}

$products = $query->get();
```

This is great and I like this method and I now want to have a similar functionality on only users products.

For example, id like to:

```
$products = (Auth::user()->products)->newQuery();

if($request->get('category')){
  $products->whereHas('category',function($q) use($request){
     $q->where('category_id',$request->get('category'));
  });
}

$products = $query->get();
```

But I can't do this I get newQuery() method is not available.

Is there a better way of performing optional queries based on parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to this to make it work:

```
$products = Product::where('user_id', auth()->id());

if (request('category')) {
    $products = $products->whereHas('category', function($q) {
        $q->where('category_id', request('category'));
    });
}

$products = $products->get();
```

Alternatively, you could just load related products using [lazy eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading):

```
auth()->user()->load(['products' => function($q) {
    if (request('category')) {
        $q->whereHas('category', function($q) {
            $q->where('category_id', request('category'));
        });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I feel like that could be simpler, Ive not tried but can we not use $query = Auth::user()->products()->newQuery(); then apply the conditions as required? I don't like the idea of querying the product table by user_id when Laravel uses eloquent.

Comment: @Dev.Wol why not? You do absolutely the same with category: `where('category_id', $request->category`

Comment: @Dev.Wol I've also added another less verbose solution.

Comment: no objection I guess, just my overactive desire to keep code clean ha! thanks that seems to clear things up.

Answer (score 2):

Just for a bit of neatness you can use the when() method on the builder class too

```
auth()->user()->products()
    ->when($request->category, function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereCategoryId($request->category);
    })->get();
```

or

```
Product::whereUserId(auth()->id())
    ->when($request->category, function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereCategoryId($request->category);
    })->get();
```